# EMF generation by rotating rod without magnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-current, electrical-resistance, rigid-body-dynamics

what is the EMF generated by a conducting rotating rod of mass $m$ and length $l$ in free space without magnetic field. the rod is roating with angular speed $w$? also find the current if the rod has a varying resistivity ρ= ρx

Comment: Interesting question. Intuitively for superconductors... zero. For perfect insulators... zero. Would it be different for finite conductivity for ionic conductors vs. metals?